# How to sort column based on null/not null values using Spring Repository?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am using Spring Data with MongoDB. I have a requirement where I want to sort on a field, but show rows with null values at the last. In case of SQL we would write following query

```
select myField
   from MyTable
   order by case when myField is null then 1 else 0 end, myField
```

but I am not able to find out a way to sort using PagingAndSortingRepository. How do we define the Sort object?

Want to sort it ASC, and the field type is String

Comment: Do you want sort in ASC ou DESC order? And which type is your field, a string?

Comment: want to sort in ASC, and the field type is String

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You mentioned that your requirement is *show* rows with null at the last, so why not you sort the query as usual and then put null values at the end programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [section 6.3.3 of Spring Data MongoDB](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html#d0e4140) about type-safe query. You can implement QueryDslPredicateExecutor on your repository interface:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Person> {

   // additional finder methods go here

}
```

And you can use this method:

```
List<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, OrderSpecifier<?>... orders);
```

The [OrderSpecifier](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/OrderSpecifier.html) constructor takes a [NullHandling enumeration](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/OrderSpecifier.NullHandling.html) parameter which you can set to NullsFirst / NullsLast.

Comment: I didn't try it out. Switched to MySQL as the app didn't have any specific requirement of MongoDB. Your answer still seems to be only way.

Comment: Spring Data MongoDB link is 404